# Count number of repeats in Swift

Tags: swift, count, repeat

I want to know how am I supposed to count the number of time a loop has repeated itself? More specifically how do I extract and output the number of repeats?

```
var x = 20
while x < 100 {
x += 10
}
```

The loop has executed 8 times in order to get x == 100. Is there a way to extract the number '8' so it can be used somewhere else (e.g. to make it a variable elsewhere)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it yourself: you want to count. So count!

```
var x = 20
var numtimes = 0
while x < 100 {
    x += 10
    numtimes += 1 // count!
}
numtimes // 8
```